# What does this mean in a Python script?

Tags: python

```
my_array = annotationIm[:,:,1]
```

the annotation is an image with an annotation mask of size r x c x 3, Layer 1 is the image annotation of both fat and meat of a salami, layer 2 is just the fat, and layer 3 is the meat. the pixel value is 1 in the annotation and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: See the duplicate's answers explaining numpy slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an rgb image, then you get the "g"-matrix showing the amoght of green for each pixel. As a r*c matrix.